# How to change desktop icon size in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons, 16.10

I just changed from 16.04 to 16.10 and to my dismay, I can't figure out how to reduce the desktop icon's size. Before I would just open a file browser(nautilus) and then go to preferences and then change zoom level which would effect everything including the desktop icon sizes, but now I can't find that option. Is there a way to do it from the command line or from anywhere else? I want to reduce the icon size on my desktop. I searched on this site and other stack related sites but couldn't find anything for Ubuntu 16.10. All of the solutions were for older versions. Or is there a way I can download the older nautilus version by removing the current one. I don't want to re-install 16.04, I just happened to install 16.10 without knowing that it's not LTS.

Thanks

Comment: the nautilus in 16.10 only has 3 sizes, by default you should be using the smallest. The setting is in the dropdown from one of those icons in the right side of the toolbar, it's a little slider. If I were you I'd bite the bullet & get 16.04

Comment: If you want/need a LTS then you better reinstall 16.04 because you won't have another until April 2018 (18.04). 16.10 and all the subsequent interim releases are supported for 9 months only.

Answer (score 2):

From the launcher, type "Nautilus", which will give you the file explorer under the confusing title "File".  Then, go to Edit -> Preferences.  (Do not go to File -> Properties!)  "Icon View Defaults" and "List View Defaults" are there; use them.

Boy, this is confusing!