# Ubuntu 16.10. how to resize fonts and icon?

Tags: 16.10

After upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, all icons and fonts in desktop and in files (nautilus) are larger in size. Also, all fonts in windows title bar and menu bar are larger.  How may I change them both?

Comment: These area related http://askubuntu.com/questions/840613/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size-in-ubuntu-16-10, http://askubuntu.com/questions/841808/how-to-resize-icons-to-smaller-size-on-the-desktop-ubuntu-16-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the upgrade that your resolution changed - pls check in ystem Settings - Displays` and if you use propriatory drivers, check if those are installed.

Also in `System-Settings - Displays` there is a slider named `Scale for menu and title bars` which changes system wide theme settings, some applications though might need extra changes.

The View and Behaviour of `Nautilus` can be changed in an open window via `Files-Preferences`.

The best place for almost all Settings regarding look&feel of your desktop is `dconf-editor` - which needs to be installed first.

Comment: I have already tried that. But what about size icons and text in desktop and nautilus?

Comment: to be honest I believe in your case this has  to do with the update, I therefore edited the answer -pls see the new first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, I manually went to `dconf-editor` searched for all proeprties with icon in their name and finally found this:

```
org -> gnome -> nautilus -> icon view -> default zoom level
```

For me it was set on `larger` and the `use default value` was off. I set it on `standard` since I don't have many icons there. YMMV